# How to get a single document from Firestore without using currentuser id in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter: I am trying to get a single document from firestore without passing CurrentUser ID in the document. If I hard code the document id like this, `firestoreInstance.collection("users").doc('jkdjkfjskldfjklsdj').get()`,  I am getting the result. But, when I try to get the result without using the exact document id then it fails. I want to use the auto-generated document id, not the CurrentUser id.

**Note: I don't want to use the CurrentUser id in the document since only the admin user is going to do all the work in this App.**

Here is the coding part:

```
    void _onPressed() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(id).get().then((value){
      print(value.data());
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should store the auto generated document id somewhere in the app at the moment that you create it. So that way you could access that ID whenever you want to get the document.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving all data in a collection:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await db.collection("users").get();
 for( QueryDocumentSnapshot item in querySnapshot.docs){
   Map<String, dynamic> data = Map();
     data = item.data();
       
print(data);
```

}

If you want to save data in the database, you can use this code, the documents will be generated with random values:

```
DocumentReference ref = await db.collection("users")
.add({
"name": "Ahamed",
"age": "30"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am looking to get Single Document data from a collection by passing the Document Id instead of CurrentUser id. Here is the example code -> db.collection("users").doc(documentId).get()

Comment: If you have the DocumentId value, you can use this.

DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await db.collection ("users"). doc (documentId) .get (), your data is in "snapshot.data"

Comment: What you say is to hard code the documentId but I need to pass the documentId dynamically Instead of hard coding. How do I pass the documentId dynamically?

Comment: You need some reference to retrieve a single data, you can retrieve the value of "doc" the moment you create this document, according to the second code in my post, with the variable "ref" you can retrieve this id using "ref .id "

Answer (score 0):

If you are not entering the exact id then use this

```
    DocumentSnapshot doc;
doc=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").where('id',isGreaterThanEqualTo:yourId).get();
if(doc==null)
doc=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").where('id',isLessThanEqualTo:yourId).get();
```

and then use the snapshot to get data.

Comment: Deepak, I don't want to generate a random Id. All I need is to get the data from the collection using the document Id.

Comment: Will you be entering the exact document id or there maybe chances that the id you enter may not exist

Comment: I don't enter the exact document id instead I need to pass the document id dynamically in the collection.

Comment: Should I use document() or where() because document() is giving me an error and what to be replaced for "yourId" ?

Comment: Ya didn't realised its where not document have changed it and replace yourId with the dynamic id that admin gonna enter like in your question it is-'jkdjkfjskldfjklsdj'.